# Condição if com required ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar um if para required em uma ViewModel.
Por exemplo eu tenho estas duas variáveis:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatorio.")]
    [Display(Name = "Insc. Estadual")]
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Inscrição Isento")]
    public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }
```

Eu gostaria que se a `InscricaoIsento` for `true` ao realizar o submit, ele envie, e caso o campo `InscricaoEstadual` e `InscricaoIsento` não está marcado ele fizesse a validação do campo `InscricaoEstadual` como obrigatório, tem como fazer isto em uma `ViewModel` ?

Comment: `[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage="O campo inscrição isento precisa ser marcado!")]
public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }`

Comment: Você abriu essa pergunta dia 24/09 e ela já foi respondida, eu testei antes de responder e a validação funcionava.

Então você abriu há dois dias essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-required-com-if-viewmodel

Há 1 hora atrás você abriu essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333383/validationresult-com-dois-par%C3%A2metros....e agora **editou** essa pergunta novamente :-(...

Comment: @Renan estou tentando algo que funciona, não sei porque não está funcionando.Até editei a pergunta pra ficar mais claro, eu abri outra, porque achei que o problema não fosse essa validação, então estava tentando outras formas.

Comment: @Renan eu abri as outras, pois estava tentando de outra forma, já que esta não está funcionando. Me desculpe a confusão.

Comment: Entendo, mas, quando você pergunta e marca uma resposta como respondida, sua pergunta fica associada aquela resposta e servirá para dúvidas de outras pessoas também. Porém quando você dias depois edita ela, meio que a resposta deixa de ter sentido entendeu? *Sugestão*: Voltar a pergunta como estava. Pegar uma das outras que você abriu, deixá-la bem completa, para tentarmos ajudar.

Comment: @Renan editei está aqui, se puder me ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333383/validationresult-com-dois-par%C3%A2metros Obrigado.

Comment: Editei a resposta para ficar completa, assim você pode testar e ver o que você estava fazendo errado que não funcionava para você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é fazer uma validação customizada.

Para criar a validação customizada sua classe de *Model* precisa implementar o método `Validate` de `IValidatableObject`, dentro do método `Validate` você implementa a sua lógica de validação, assim:

Model:

```
public class SeuModel : IValidatableObject
{
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatorio.")]
    [Display(Name = "Insc. Estadual")]
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Inscrição Isento")]
    public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (InscricaoIsento == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(InscricaoEstadual))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("O campo Insc. Estadual é obrigatorio.");
         }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SeuController : Controller
{
    // GET: Seu
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SeuModel seuModel)
    {
        return View(seuModel);
    }
}
```

Index:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SeuModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SeuModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InscricaoIsento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InscricaoIsento)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InscricaoIsento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InscricaoEstadual, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InscricaoEstadual, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InscricaoEstadual, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Validação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]