# Validação required com if ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando fazer a validação de campos com a ViewModel
Desta forma não está funcionando:

```
 [Display(Name = "Insc. Estadual")]
public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Inscrição Isento")]
public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (InscricaoIsento == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(InscricaoEstadual))
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("O campo Insc. Estadual é obrigatorio.");
     }
}
```

Se o campo `InscricaoIsento` for `false` e `InscricaoEstadual` for vazio, ele informa que o campo é obrigatório. 
Esta função não está funcionando, não consigo entender porque, está na `ViewModel.`

Comment: Se usar a notação de [Required] pode ser que lhe atenda.

Comment: Se o campo InscricaoIsento for false e InscricaoEstadual for vazio, ele informa que o campo é obrigatório. Mas se o campo InscricaoIsento for true, o InscricaoEstadual não precisa ser preenchido Infelizmente não atend.e

Comment: Isso já não foi respondido aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331767/condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-if-com-required-viewmodel/331806#331806 ? **Senão**, coloque mais informações nessa pergunta, como o código completo do Model e a Action da Controller para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: @Renan ele não está funcionando.

Comment: Coloque mais informações nessa pergunta, como o código completo do Model e a Action da Controller para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Eu só preciso da validação do campo, porém como if como descrito, desta forma não está validando.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, tente fazer assim:

```
[Display(Name = "Insc. Estadual")]
[Required]
public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Inscrição Isento")]
[Required]
public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }
```

Incluindo o [Required] nos seus campos.

Comment: Se o campo InscricaoIsento for false e InscricaoEstadual for vazio, ele informa que o campo é obrigatório.  Mas se o campo InscricaoIsento for true, o InscricaoEstadual não precisa ser preenchido.

Comment: Ah, ok! Tebte fazer via javascript. Chamando uma validacao no evento OnClick

Answer (score -1):

Seu view model está herdando do `IValidatableObject`?
Tente assim:

```
public class Empresa : IValidatableObject
```

Comment: Eu fiz, mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Em seu controller, você fez a validação do ModelState.ValidationState?

Comment: Ele faz a validação `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: A fim de teste, experimenta colocar os campos afetados na validação no construtor, dessa maneira: yield return new ValidationResult("O campo Insc. Estadual é obrigatorio.", new[] { "InscricaoIsento "});

Comment: Já está assim, conforme na pergunta.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas, na pergunta está utilizando um construtor com apenas um parâmetro, sendo este a mensagem de erro, o que eu sugeri é utilizar o construtor de dois parâmetros, informando a mensagem de erro e a lista de variáveis afetadas.

Comment: É pq quando vi o comentário ainda estava igual, fiz o teste e mesmo assim não funcionou.